# Excel formula or VBA searching for matching values, every matching value found move to new column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to excel and have very basic knowledge of it. I hope that some one will by able to help me as I'm trying  to find similar formula or VBA code for few days now and no luck.

I need formula or VBA to find same value in range and when first matching value find move to new column.
For example:
 Value in A1 check against all values in column H and if same value found move that value to B1, then again value in A1 check against values left in H column if same found  move to C1, every time finds A1 same as value in H column moves that value to new column D1, E1 .....continue until all values in H column have been checked and matching ones moved. After this value in A2 checked against all values in H column and all matching values moved to B2,C2,E2 etc. Continue until all values have been moved from column H.

**This how data looks before moving:**

```html
 0     A      B      C      D      E      F      G    H
 ----------------------------------------------------------
1    123                                            123
2    256                                            123
3    333                                            123
4                                                   123
5                                                   123
6                                                   256
7                                                   256
8                                                   333
9                                                   333 
10                                                  333
11                                                  333
12                                                  333
13                                                  333
```

**After movment:**

```html
    0         A      B       C        D      E      F      G     H
     ----------------------------------------------------------
    1    123    123     123      123    123    123                      
    2    256    256     256                                  
    3    333    333     333      333    333    333    333                    
    4                                                   
    5                                                   
    6                                                   
    7                                                   
    8                                                   
    9                                                    
    10                                                  
    11
```

Comment: Generally, requests like this that don't show any code do not get a positive response as Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.  You need to break your solution into steps, and then start researching how to accomplish each step and write some code.  If your code doesn't work, then post it here with details and you'll probably get a quick response that will be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry I will try next time. In this case I wasn't  sure how  even to start writing the code to sort this issue  as my VBA level is very basic.

Comment: No problem--just trying to help you get what you need--looks like someone came through for you!  Be sure to mark it as the accepted answer (if it works) so they get credit for it and other readers will know that it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:-

```
Sub tester()
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address)
        i = 1
        For Each c In .Range("H1:" & .Range("H1").End(xlDown).Address)
            If cell.Value = c.Value Then
                cell.Offset(0, i).Value = c.Value
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Note: This does not clear the results from run to run.

Comment: It works as as described, just not deleting values after moved but this is not that important.